# Setting custom RejectedExecutionHandler for ThreadPoolExecutor after executing some tasks?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I am using Java ThreadPoolExecutor in one of my Android components. My question is that :

Is it a good practice to set RejectedExecutionHandler using setRejectedExecutionHandler() after executing some tasks to the TPE ?

I mean are there any side effects of doing this. Is it a good practice?

**Edited**

I am required to create a ThreadPoolManagementLibrary project in Android which can be used by other projects. Now, I need to expose public methods of TPE in my component. If I let the user set RejectedExecutionHandler then would it be a problem?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I think the rejection policy should be clear and stable.

Answer (score 3):

The question should be "Should we handle the RejectedExecutionException?". The answer is of course yes. Not doing so will crash the thread in which it occurs i.e. the thread submitting the task for execution, and the application will continue running in an unknown state.

The second question is "What should we do to handle this exception?". We should probably stop the application as cleanly as possible. As this is true also for other runtime exceptions (and errors, by the way), one solution is to use an UncaughtExceptionHandler. But if we want to handle the RejectedExecutionException in a specific manner, we may use a RejectedExecutionHandler. This could be used to do some specific handling before stopping the application (either directly or by throwing a new RuntimeException that will be caught by the UncaughtExceptionHandler).

The main point here is that all exceptions and errors should be handled. This is against so call "best practices", but these practices are just wrong. They were right once for single thread applications. The world has changed. A runtime exception or an error will crash the thread in which it occurs, not the application. So it MUST BE HANDLED.

Of course, if you are using a framework or an application server, the problem may be different because this server or framework will probably handle the uncaught exceptions for you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Let us try to understand what a RejectedExecutionHandler  does?

When you submit submit a task to the ThreadPoolExecutor then following sequence of event happens:

- If there is any worker thread free which is free and can run this task.
- Else it will try to move this task to the workerqueue from where a worker thread will pick up the task if it is free.
- If the workerQueue is also full then it will try to create a new thread if possible(no of worker threads are less than maxPoolSize).
- If all the above fails then the task is sent to the handler and the default handler throws a RejectedExecutionException.

So basically, if you allow user to set their own handler then you are giving them freedom to handle the rejected task in their own way. They should be careful while implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would also agree with @user2120553 .
All the points @Braj Kishore mentioned are correct, but I would like to mention that if we declare our custom `RejectedExecutionHandler` then we would surely get a chance to retry the execution.